# Rails: Relation with class_name does not get saved properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a (rather simple) model representing a comment:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

    STATES = [:processing, :accepted, :declined]

    belongs_to :note
    belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User'

    validates_inclusion_of :state, :in => STATES
    validates_presence_of :author

    default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'

    def initialize( attributes={} )
        super(attributes)

        self.state ||= 'processing'
    end
end
```

However, everytime I save a comment (with its fields set properly), the author relation always fails to save (well, actually the comment saves successfully, it just leaves out the author...). This goes as far as `Comment.first.valid?` returning `false` due to the validation on the author field (`Comment.first.author` is `nil`).

My suspicion is that I handle the default value for state-field in a wrong way? If so, how should I set the default value instead?

thx for your help in advance

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Comment: Does this happen only on creation of a new comment or also when you update existing comments?

Comment: It does also happen when I update an existing comment

Comment: Another strange behaviour I just realized in the rails console: I set `comment.author` manually, and call `comment.save!` afterwards. When I display the comment-object by simply entering `comment` into the prompt, it states in the object summary "`Comment id: [...], author: nil, [...]`". However, if I type `comment.author`, it displays the author I just assigned.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using `ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i386-mingw32]` and `Rails 3.0.4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the state attribute, it would be better to use an `after_initialize` callback to set the default instead of overriding the initialize function :

```
def after_initialize 
 self.state ||= 'processing'
end
```

To properly override a function you should pass params and args this way :

```
def initialize(*args,&block)
  super(*args,&block)
  #what-you-want-to-execute
end
```

Notice that there is often a better way than using this !

Comment: for your problem, change your validation to : `validates_presence_of :author_id` , see the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of)

Comment: If the column in the DB is author, I would think that you have to set on the belongs_to association because it will automatically look on column `author_id`, try : `belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'author'`